# Having Troubles with SpeechRecognition Library (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition')

Tags: python

so I've been trying to code a virtual assistant, but I'm having trouble with the library SpeechRecognition. The error is: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition')` regarding the line `import speech_recognition as sr`. I'm using IDLE to run Python 3.7.7 on Windows 10. My version of pip is 20.1 and when installing the SpeechRecognition library I used the command `pip3 install --user SpeechRecognition` and it downloaded successfully. So that's all the information that I thought relevant to my problem, and the same with the code. Thanks!

Comment: Run `pip3 --version` and check if it uses the same Python version

Comment: It says that the version of pip is 3.7, so I think that's the same version as my python.